# How many legs on the Bus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

This is a very basic pre-algebra problem.  I think I solved it (pretty confident) and went to check to see if there were any posted solutions online.  Of course, anyone can answer, so there are a myriad of different answers.  Here's the problem, then my solution.

> There are 7 girls on a bus.
>
> Each girl has 7 backpacks.
>
> In each backpack, there are 7 big cats.
>
> For every big cat, there are 7 little cats.
>
> Question:  How many legs are there in the bus (minus the driver)?

So, if there is a big cat, there are seven little cats, so 32 cat legs per big cat.

There are 7 big cats per back pack, so there are 224 cat legs per back pack.

But there are 7 back packs per girl, so there are 1568 cat legs per girl.

But there are 7 girls on the bus, so there are 10976 cat lets on the bus.

But there are 7 girls with 2 legs each.  So 14 girl legs.

So 10976+14=10990 total lets.

Is this correct?  Many sites give a much lower answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything looks correct, except you forgot the bus driver.